# Use Algebraic Means to Determine Limit $\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{2 - |x|}{2 + x}$

Tags: calculus

I'm attempting to understand a particular step taken on our answer sheet for the following problem.

Find the Following Limit using Algebraic Means: $$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{2-|x|}{2+x}$$

The answer is laid out as follows.

If $x$ is near $-2$; $|x| = -x$

$$\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{2-(-x)}{2+x}$$

I pretty well understand the rest.  However, it is that first line there, "if $x$ is near $-2$", that I do not understand.  Why am I able to make the leap that $|x| = -x$ when evaluating the limit in this case?

Comment: If you write out the definition for the function "absolute value" in piecewise form, what does the piece look like for when $x$ is negative?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial on Mathjax, take a look to better edit your question.

Answer (score 2):

As $$ |x| = \begin{cases}x \,\,, \, \text{if}\,\,x\geq 0\\-x \, \, , \, \text{if}\,\, x < 0\end{cases}$$ and you are taking $\delta > 0$ sufficiently small such that $x \in (-2-\delta, -2+\delta) \implies x < 0$, it follows that $|x| = -x$.